# mySQL condition of a value in a column not occuring

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, left-join

The idea is that I need to list all students that have never failed at all ever, and this includes students which are yet to take any exams at all. A few points:

`studentId` is a student's unique ID.
`studentLastname` obviously student's last name.
`examEntryStudentId` is student's unique ID foreign key.
`examEntryNumber` is unique exam number for students.
`examInfoNumber` is the same but on `ExamInfo` table.
`examInfoPassed` determines whether a student passed or not, 1 means they passed (above 50%) and 0 means they failed.

The idea is that I traverse through the tables from `Student` to `ExamEntry` to `ExamInfo`. I want all Students to first be possibly chosen as those that are in younger terms have not yet taken an - official - exam so I'm making use of a `LEFT JOIN` so that all are picked as they otherwise won't appear as they are not contained within `examEntryStudentId` as not all students have taken exams. Furthermore, you then use the `ExamEntry` table to traverse over to the `ExamInfo` table where the data of whether a student has failed an exam is stored. This data is stored under `examInfoPassed`, so if a student has ever had the value of `0` in `examInfoPassed` it means that they should be the only students not included in my output.

This is my initial code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.studentId, l.studentLastname
FROM Students l
LEFT JOIN ExamEntry e
ON l.studentId = e.examEntryStudentId
JOIN ExamInfo a
ON e.examEntryNumber = a.examInfoNumber
WHERE NOT a.examInfoPassed = 0
;
```

Though my output is currently any student that passed a test, including students that have previously failed  a test. I'm unsure of how to make a condition that means that if you fall into the category of `NOT a.examInfoPassed = 0` then they are removed from the output. Also students that have not taken any tests are also not included in my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sql code, currently your query reports all students that have passed *at least on exam*, while you want those who passed *all exams*. Also, students that never passed any exams are excluded, because the `WHERE` clause references a column coming from a JOINed table.

You need to change your logic :

- use `LEFT JOIN`s to detect those who failed at least one exam
- then exclude them in the `WHERE` clause (in the meantime, this will allow students who never took exam to be included in the output list).

Query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.studentId, l.studentLastname
FROM Students l
LEFT JOIN ExamEntry e ON l.studentId = e.examEntryStudentId
LEFT JOIN ExamInfo a ON e.examEntryNumber = a.examInfoNumber AND a.examInfoPassed = 0
WHERE a.examInfoNumber IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm confused by your second `LEFT JOIN` as it contains 2 `ON` conditions? This causes a syntax error.

Comment: @bemzoo, I just fixed that typo

Comment: The way I solved that was by: `LEFT JOIN ExamInfo a ON (e.examEntryNumber = a.examInfoNumber AND a.examInfoPassed = 0)`

Comment: @bemzoo, yep ; you are free to remove the parens `()` around the conditions, they are not mandatory in mysql.

Comment: What if a student was entered into an exam, though based on some data input error, even though they were on the `ExamEntry` table, they were never input onto the `ExamInfo` table. Would there be a way to include those possible students in the output?

Comment: In such use case, `a.examInfoNumber` will end up with a `NULL` value in the `WHERE` clause (because the `LEFT JOIN` on `ExamInfo` will not happen) : hence the student will be included in the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184972/discussion-between-bemzoo-and-gmb).

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation instead:

```
SELECT l.studentId, l.studentLastname
FROM Students l LEFT JOIN
     ExamEntry e
     ON l.studentId = e.examEntryStudentId LEFT JOIN
     ExamInfo a
     ON e.examEntryNumber = a.examInfoNumber
GROUP BY  l.studentId, l.studentLastname
HAVING MIN(a.examInfoPassed) = 0 OR MIN(a.examInfoPassed) IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is still displaying only students that have taken part in an exam, the students that have an `examEntryStudentId`, also all students that have failed an exam but passed others still show on the output. For the final aggregation when deciding students that have never taken an exam, it's not that they have `NULL` values for examInfoPassed it is that they don't have any values at all, they have no data in that the `ExamInfo` table at all. Is there anyway to reference the `studentId` and `studentLastname` pairs that have no data in the `ExamInfo` table?

Comment: @bemzoo . . . Both the `JOIN`s should be `LEFT JOIN`s.  I somehow missed that in the original answer.